# How to transition out of a role I don't feel suited for?

Tags: team-role, position

I work in technology for a large financial institution. I was hired two years ago as a software developer and had a lot fun and a fair amount of success in that position.

I'm still, technically, in that position, but the nature of my work has changed dramatically. I got pulled into a large project that directly impacts my team and have become the primary point of contact between the project and my team.

The trouble is that I consider myself a creative person and the work I'm currently doing lacks many of the characteristics that I value in a role. I'm now doing work that I feel is more in line with a project manager or analyst - work that I can do, but which I'm neither trained nor well-suited for. My job satisfaction has suffered tremendously as a result, as has my drive. I'm simply uninspired by the work that I'm doing and find it hard to motivate myself.

My company has numerous other areas in technology and more than a few open positions in software development. I don't want to leave the company, nor, really, leave my team. I'd just like to get back to what I was doing when I was hired - creating software.

How can I communicate my desire for change to my management? Am I stuck with this until the project ends, and, if that's the case, how can I pick up where I left off?

Comment: Have you communicated this to your manager?

Comment: @LawrenceAiello In parts. I'm sort of afraid that this desire will be a career limiting move.

Comment: Well then quite honestly, you work in a hostile environment and I would get out if I was you. What is more career limiting: being in a job you hate or just finding another one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion is to have a meeting with your manager, or whoever made the decision to move you, and tell them exactly what you have stated above. Make sure to highlight why you feel that you would better help **the company** by being a software developer, not you, because whoever made this decision made it because they feel you would have been better for the company there.

Also be careful not to hint at leaving the company. In all honesty....this could be a play by them to force you out if they knew you were dissatisfied. If they fail to move you back into a software developer position, I would find another job.

Comment: I think you make a great point about how my desire would help the company. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually, this is a career limiting move, and that doesn't mean the environment is hostile.  Any time you tell management that there are certain jobs/tasks that you do not want to do, you are placing limits on their ability to advance your career.

You need to decide for yourself how much you want to work for this company.  If this company or department goes through any down-sizing or re-org, you have limited what options they have for you.  If nothing happens with the company, you may never see the difference, but if you are "just another developer", you could be the unlucky one out.

Unfortunately, many companies (in my experience) don't have nearly robust a technical career path as they do managerial.  So anything you say you don't wish to do can put more limits on an already limited career path.

I'm not suggesting that you should just put up with what ever they ask you to do, but I think it is important that you understand the ripple effect this can have.